# I made a tin can phone using a plastic slinky and paper cups. Why didn't it work?

Tags: waves, acoustics, everyday-life

After watching some videos on Khan academy in regards to the information theory, I spent a few minutes creating a primitive ["tin can phone."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tin_can_telephone) The materials of my phone are a plastic slinky and two paper cups.

I pierced the bottom of both cups with the edges of the slinky and tried communicating with my partner a few metres away. It was a total failure.
Also, I tried strumming the string, but, again, the sound didn't reach the other side.

An explanation of the how and why this happened and maybe some tips for next time would be great.

Comment: I have a feeling that the curled plastic string is difficult to fully stretch and too soft. To let the sound wave propagate without loss you must give it no other choice than to move linearly through the string - not to the sides.

Comment: Hmmm.. In my mind, I compared it to the curled telephone strings, I didn't think that the sound wave would lose that much of its intensity by simply traveling on a curled surface.

Edit: christ, I thought that "enter" would simply skip a line, instead of finishing the message.

Post edit:

If I would use a metal curled slinky/ a plastic stick, do you think the results would be better? =o

Comment: But as far as I know the whole point is that the string is stretched out. Just think about how the wave propagates. If it propagates in a moving medium the wave might translate the medium instead of propagating. Same thing when you hold a rope in one end and "jolts" a wave through it; the more stretched the rope is, the further the waves goes. If it's loose, the wave will only push the rope around and not propagate ad a wave. Telephone strings are way different if I'm not wrong - they don't transport sound as sound waves in a medium. But I'm no expert in that field

Comment: Good point, noted :)
I think I'm getting the hang of it!
If I would choose to use a non-elastic curled metal string, versus a metal slinky, where would the results be better, if at all?

Comment: Something's not adding up here. For one, this has nothing to do with information theory. Also, slinkies are used to demonstrate waves visually, but these visual waves are very much not sound waves you can hear. Did someone actually say you should use a slinky for this? Note that telephone strings curling have nothing to do with transmitting sound -- it is simply an easy way to make an extendable/retractable cord.

Comment: Hello :)
In regards to information theory, you're right, it's my bad. I brought it up since in one of the first videos they showed Alice and Bob communicating using vibrations which passed along a stretched string, that gave me the idea of attempting a tin phone in the first place, it has little to do with the theory itself, apologies.
Also, no one suggested I should a slinky for this, I chose to use a slinky because it was right in front of me while I was thinking of the idea, and I figured it would be interesting to attempt the old "tin-phone" with that twist.

Comment: Also, I understand the reason behind the curled telephone string, I was just wondering whether or not it should affect the effectiveness of transmission in any way, since from what I understand, the curling apparently did affect the effectiveness of my tin phone (of course I may very well be wrong and the curling has nothing to do with how well the sound transmits).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am basing this almost completely on the comments above and my own experience of making a "tin can phone" as a kid.

The string was pulled as tight as we could get it, on the basis that a loose string, i.e. no tension, would not carry the sound waves very far.

But the tension in the string also makes the base of the cup vibrate, increasing your chances of getting your shouting into your "phone" being carried down the wire and setting up matching vibrations on the base at the far end.

So, in theory at least, you shout into the phone, the base of the cup vibrates in a certain pattern, the tense string carries that pattern down to the base of the other cup, and it vibrates in the same pattern.

In reality, as far as I remember, I had to shout soooo loud that the other guy could hear me anyway, phone or no phone.

[Tin Can Phone: Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tin_can_telephone)

> Sound waves are created as the air vibrates in response to a person's speech or other sounds. A second person's ear collects these sound waves and converts them into nerve impulses which their brain interprets as sound. In normal speech these waves travel through the air, but with a tin can telephone the waves are transmitted through an additional medium of cups and string.
>
> When the string is pulled taut and someone speaks into one of the cans, its bottom acts as a diaphragm, converting the sound waves into longitudinal mechanical vibrations which vary the tension of the string. These variations in tension set up longitudinal waves in the string which travel to the second can, causing its bottom to vibrate in a similar manner as the first can, thus recreating the sound heard by the second person.
>
> The signal can be directed around corners with the aid of a third can positioned on the apex of the corner. The string is threaded through the base of the third can so as to avoid coming into contact with the object around which the signal is to be directed.

[The 600 feet Tin Can Phone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WPnYLD2awFc)  A video that could really use some editing, far too long, just skip to the last minute.

Comment: Thanks for the response :)
So technically, where did I go wrong with my attempt? I mean, it was all there, and the video you showed - presented a well working tin phone, which remained very much effective across a rather large distance, especially compared to the metre and a half or so which I tried.
Would using tougher materials such as tin, improve the effectiveness of my phone? and how much did the slinky shape damage the effectiveness of the transmission, or was it only the material which interrupted the transmission?
Thanks very much and sorry for the newbish questions. =)

Comment: Mainly just the tension, it needs to be pulled tight, and a light but strong base to your phone